# Wait for map to finish and then write a log with Promise

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple application that will go through DialogFlow (Google) and send me the intents that were picked up based on the users comment.

I have the following code.

```
let writeToExcel = [];



 var promises = xlData.map(data => {
   detectIntentText(data.QUESTION);
 });

 Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
   console.log(results);
   console.log(writeToExcel);
 })
```

However, the array that prints is all undefined, and it prints before the function, `detectIntentText`, finished everything in the map. There could be upwards of 1000 entries.

What is the best way to get this to work?

Here is the detectIntentText function

```
async function detectIntentText(userText) {
  const sessionId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
  const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
    projectId,
    location,
    agentId,
    sessionId
  );
  console.info(sessionPath);

  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: userText,
      },
      languageCode,
    },
  };
  const [response] = await client.detectIntent(request);
  // console.log(`User Query: ${userText}`);
  var intent = "";
  for (const message of response.queryResult.responseMessages) {
    if (message.text) {
      // console.log(`Agent Response: ${message.text.text}`);
    }
  }
  if (response.queryResult.match.intent) {
    // console.log(
    //   `Matched Intent: ${response.queryResult.match.intent.displayName}`
    //);
    intent = response.queryResult.match.intent.displayName;
  }
  // console.log(
  //   `Current Page: ${response.queryResult.currentPage.displayName}`
  // );

  let jsonToWrite = {
    CX_QUESTION: userText,
    INTENT: intent
  }

  // console.log(jsonToWrite);

  writeToExcel.push(jsonToWrite);
}
```

Comment: what is `detectIntentText()` ? is that async function?

Comment: The expression `data => {…}` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: You either need to remove the braces  `.map(data => detectIntentText(data.QUESTION))` or you need a `return`  as in: `.map(data => { return detectIntentText(data.QUESTION); })`

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning anything from `map`. If `detectIntentText()` returns `Promise`, Then your code should be

```
 var promises = xlData.map(data => {
   return detectIntentText(data.QUESTION);
 });

 Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
   console.log(results);
   console.log(writeToExcel);
 })
```

You can get rid of the `return` keyword like this,

```
var promises = xlData.map(data => detectIntentText(data.QUESTION));
```

Comment: i updated my question with the detectintenttext function.

Comment: Please check for duplicates before answering

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you for mentioning this. I am sorry, Won't happen again

Comment: No problem at all :)